# Sequelize config model validate max min why it don't work

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs

code model in nestjs

```
@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(15),
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      min: 9,
      max: 15,
    },
})
mobile: string;
```

when I create this model by create function
mobile length 10 - 15 show error
Validation error: Validation max on mobile failed
but I try to reduce length of mobile until 2 it can create the table

Comment: min, max is for integer validation whether value is grater than or less than the value you set. In order to validate the length of value, you use `len`. Ref: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html#per-attribute-validations

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the solution and I found that sequelize-typescript for nestjs use another code to setting min, max

```
import { Length, Column } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Length({max:15, min:12})
@Column({
type: DataType.STRING(15),
allowNull: false,
// validate: {
//  min: 9,
//  max: 15,
// },
})
mobile: string;
```